# JavaScript RegEx for Java Comments

Tags: javascript, java, regex

1. I am trying to capture the string/lines starting with /* ending with */, basically this is comments in java.

Something like

```
/* Line 1 
 * Line 2
 * Line 3
 */
```

This is what I have at present, this is partially working

```
(\/*\/|\*.*)
```

2. Want to capture string starting with `<!--` and ending with `-->`

`<!-- line 1 -->`

I have tried with

```
 var comments = /(<!--.*-->)/gm;
```

But it's not working, as I have another regEx for < and >

```
 var symb = /(<|>)/gi;
 $(this).text().replace(symb,"<span class='blue'>$1</span>")
```

Comment: How is your second example not working for you?

Comment: What should happen if the comments are inside `" "` marks?

Comment: `// This is a one line comment /* Still a one line comment`

Comment: Just curious who given -1 ? if you want to contribute, help like CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 2):

To capture `/*` to `*/`, you could try something like this:

```js
const re = /\/\*([\s\S](?!\*\/))+[\s\S]\*\//;
const str = `
noncomment
/* Line 1
 * Line 2
 * Line 3
 */
noncomment
`;
console.log(str.match(re)[0]);
```

The same sort of pattern works for HTML comments:

```js
const re = /<!--([\s\S](?!-->))+[\s\S]-->/;
const str = `
noncomment
<!-- Line 1
  Line 2
  Line 3
 -->
noncomment
`;
console.log(str.match(re)[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend its working perfectly! but second one is failing problem is, for < i am applying other regex which surrounds < with <span/> that's the reason /<!--([\s\S](?!-->))+[\s\S]-->/; is not taking.

Is there any way to pick only < whose next character is not !

Comment: Can you post in your question an example of the text you're working with for which the regular expression fails?

Comment: Sounds like you should move the HTML comment tester above the `symb` replacer. If that's not an option, then post what the HTML looks like after the `symb` replacer runs

Comment: Let's say the line is <!-- my comment -->

without symb, your code /<!--([\s\S](?!-->))+[\s\S]-->/ will work. As you suggested I can move comment tester above symb, but later symb will run and its changing the < and > :-)

With comment testers I always want to show text in green color, but symb is changing < and >, seems little challenging.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler pattern, this uses `[^]` as a pseudo "[anything including newlines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)" token, combined with a non-greedy quantifier:

```js
const re = /\/\*[^]*?\*\//;
const str = `
noncomment
/**** Line 1
 * Line 2
 * Line 3
 ***/
noncomment
`;
console.log(str.match(re)[0]);
```